# Why does a router need 2 IP address?

Tags: router, ipv4, network

Suppose there are 2 PC and 1 router in "LAN1", now if PC1 wants to communicate with PC2, it will need to uniquely identify PC2. So, PC2 gets a private IP that no other PC in LAN1 will have.

Now a router already has a public IP, so it can be uniquely identified by its public IP, then why does it need a private IP(Default Gateway)?

Comment: Routers often have many IP addresses, one (or more) for each interface (physical and virtual).

Comment: Router is layer3 device . It has feasible to configure neither public ip or private ip , its depends upon requirements and design .. however private ip address used in internal LAN which are hided by NATing for translating private ip address to public ip address .